# Argument of type 'FC<ComponentType>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ForwardRefRenderFunction<unknown, ComponentType>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using react with typescript. I have two components, one is a child and the other one is a parent. I am forwarding `ref` to my child component and in my child component I binding my export with `forwardRef` but I am getting an error on export line saying: `Argument of type 'FC<ComponentType>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ForwardRefRenderFunction<unknown, ComponentType>'`

Here is my code:

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react';
import './Label.css';

type LabelType = {
    name: string
    ref: any
}

const Label: React.FC<LabelType> = ({name, ref}) => {
  return <label className='label' ref={ref}>
</label>;
};

export default forwardRef(Label);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) explains how `forwardRef` works: you must define the `ref` as the *second* parameter of the function component (instead of including it in the props, which is the first parameter). Then pass your function component as the first argument to `forwardRef`.

> [Here is a link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/dc443a9c990f2a20db631fb9d826ad301eb558a7/types/react/index.d.ts#L810) to where the function signature for `forwardRef` is declared in the current version of the `@types/react` pacakge. You can inspect it to learn about how I derived the types in the following examples.

Here are two ways you can implement the instruction above to fix your current component:

---

Supply the appropriate generic type parameters to `forwardRef` (then you don't need to annotate the function component directly):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAGjjWgHcMolS0BfWqCEOAcijKVeAbgBQoSLD4A6APQAZDACMUOaeQIERo0SgAek+DACeYFHEUqcABS5giAXkSi4cAHYYQKAFxwCMKGA3AHMxNjFdA2h4cgg3fwtlVTgnOihGZlYAHgAJABUAWXlLVQBRHBQvN2pEq1sIewA+AApmhA8vNhoBNABKFMbnVwEYLCg3OGasnCScOHIZzQA5TxQHXhmrXjgehwQetkb21bYs2U3VRt6w6519QzhUTFx4EpwxIA)

```ts
import {default as React, forwardRef} from 'react';
import './Label.css';

export type LabelProps = {
  name: string;
};

export const Label = forwardRef<HTMLLabelElement, LabelProps>(({name}, ref) => {
  return (<label className='label' ref={ref}>{name}</label>);
});

export default Label;
```

---

Or, annotate the function component directly:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=15&ssc=22&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAGjjWgHcMolS0BfWqCEOAcijKVeAbgBQoSLD4A6APQAZDACMUOaeQIERo0SgAek+DACeYFHEUqcABS5giAXkSi4cAHYYQKAFxwCMKGA3AHMxNjFRcgg3fwtlVTgnOihGZlYACnSXRA8vNl9LVVsIeypsgTRfUgoYaQAxBiZUFnQAHgAJABUAWXlCnABRHBQvNxgAPjKASirBWurKIZGUMcTx51cBGCwoNzh01px4nDhyI80AOU8UB14jq144CocECrZxhFyUNlbZe9VxlMwkCdPpDHBUJhcPB+mIgA)

```ts
import {default as React, forwardRef} from 'react';
import './Label.css';

export type LabelProps = {
  name: string;
};

const Label = forwardRef((
  {name}: LabelProps,
  ref: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLLabelElement>,
): React.ReactElement => {
  return (<label className='label' ref={ref}>{name}</label>);
});

export default Label;
```